# Does Linkedin's Company-Search API Throttle per-user or per-IP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linkedin-api

[Request Linkedin API limit count records](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/company-search)

Today I was developing an application using linkedin company search api. [Documentation says](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/throttle-limits) that a developer registration has 500 times API calls per day.

When I have registered this api, and ran a resque scheduler – my two users should be 1000 times, right?  But actually, after some 510 calls it says throttle limit exceeds.

Did anyone face such kind of issue using linkedin api?  Comments are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The API is likely using your API key to keep track of calls, so running extra instances of your worker won't achieve a higher call cap.

In fact, it's right there in the docs you pasted:

> A developer registration has 500 times API calls per day

Comment: Ok, thanks. I changed my application live state to live. but i see the Search Companies  Call Count: 659 stoped. Should not be so.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably used the same API key/registration for each worker.

Creating different accounts/keys, and giving one to each worker, may still not solve the problem, as LinkedIn may throttle the usage per-IP.

Some testing may show otherwise, but you should consider yourself on shakey ground, and seek to build needed API usage costs into your app/business model.